# Global JavaScript exception handler (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

How do I overwrite the global Exception handler in JavaScript so that it becomes the top level handler for all uncaught exceptions?

*window.onerror* didn’t work. The code is:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script language='javascript'>
            window.onerror = function (em, url, ln) {
                alert(em + ", " + url + ", " + ln);
                return false;
            }

            function fGo() {
                try
                {
                    var a = b; // Error here: b not defined
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <button onclick='fGo()'>GO</button>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm testing on Chrome, by the way. The developer console registers the uncaught exception, but the alert() in *window.onerror* does not appear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of 2013, Chrome supports the `window.onerror`. (I have version 25, and comments imply earlier versions as well.)

I wrapped jQuery using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to create a proxy that always does a `try...catch` in the jQuery functions.

I use it in [www.js-analytics.com](http://www.js-analytics.com/). However, the solution only holds for jQuery scripts.

Before 2013 Google Chrome didn't support `window.onerror`, and apparently it wasn't implemented in [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).

Comment: That's right. And WebKit has recently made some advance on fixing that bug. It's not fixed yet, but here you have the link for updates: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8519

Comment: According to http://groups.google.com/group/js-test-driver/browse_thread/thread/14c7e6d615a2b803?pli=1 it should be fixed in Chrome 10

Comment: I'm using Chrome 14 (the latest release) and window.onerror works!

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    // Code to run when an error has occurred on the page
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

#### Chrome support for `window.onerror`

- I believe support started in Chrome v10 ([Chromium Issue 7771](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7771)), but it looks as if "full" support with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) support was resolved around Chrome 30+ ([Chromium Issue 159566](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159566))
- caniuse.com doesn't currently track this JavaScript feature ([GitHub Issue 11999](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1199)) ... to add support to this issue, log in to GitHub and "react" with a "Thumbs Up" on the original post (*don't +1 in comments*).

Current Google documentation for `window.onerror`

- [Chrome DevTools ~ Handle runtime exceptions using window.onerror](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/track-exceptions#handle_runtime_exceptions_using_windowonerror)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror). I am not sure whether this is available on all browsers.

Comment: Latest releases of Safari (and Chrome) do support it.  For reference, I confirmed on Safari 5.1 and Chrome 14, both in Mac OS X. Not sure when they were finally added to those browsers, but it's now available on all major browsers.