# Chrome: Will an error in code invoked from the dev console trigger window.onerror?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug our handling of window.onerror.  I've created a function that will throw an error (invoking another function that does not exist).  I've tried calling this first function from Chrome's web development console - an error is reported in the console, but our window.error handling function does not seem to be called.  (I've verified that window.onerror references our error handling code in the console).

**Do errors within functions invoked in the dev console not trigger window.onerror?**

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192464/window-onerror-not-working-in-chrome , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384666/global-javascript-exception-handler-in-chrome

Comment: @c69 not sure if those are duplicates because _1._ `window.onerror` is now in _Chrome_. _2._ `window.onerror` is being triggered elsewhere in code. _3._ those questions don't talk about `console`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They don't (in Chrome where I tested), easy way to test is

```
window.onerror = function () {console.log('error!');};
throw new Error();
// Error
```

You can make them do it if you defer them, though

```
window.setTimeout(function() {throw new Error()}, 0);
// error!
// Uncaught Error
```

Comment: Oh that is interesting.  Thanks for the clarification and workaround!

Comment: @RobW Interesting and may be applicable elsewhere +1, but then the question becomes "what is the origin of the `console`?" which can't be a simple answer if what you're saying is true otherwise _XHR_ wouldn't work from console. I think it is more likely that the `console` is wrapped in it's own `try..catch`.

Comment: @RobW - I thought that external scripts still invoked window.onerror, but that the error object was stripped of all useful info? Eg. The problem described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: @UpTheCreek Yes, you're right. I've deleted my previous incorrect comment.

Comment: `debugger;` is your friend. // if you look at call stack, you will see that final eval is wrapped in two try catches (Cr28).

Comment: @c69 FYI when running `debugger;` in console on Chrome 81 there is only `(anonymous) (VM2240:1)` for the call stack and can't step into it. Not sure if I'm following correctly.