# Injected JS assigning window.onerror fails to fire

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onerror

I need to run third party JS to scan jserrors. I am running the following in chrome's console

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  alert(errorMsg);
}

throw new Error('foo');
```

I expect both the console to inform me of the error and a alert to pop up displaying the error message. The alert is never fired, and I assume the event is not being fired. why not?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bS3kg/)). I'm using Chromium 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm not sure how jsFiddle deals with this but, the part that causes the issue I believe is injecting this js after the page is loaded. If you open the console in chrome and paste the code in it wil not fire

Comment: Adding an error handler by inserting a `<script>` tag works ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/bS3kg/2/)) thus I think that the Dev Console changes the behaviour somehow.

Comment: @ComFreek - "thus I think that the Dev Console changes the behavior somehow." I think you're exactly right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534054/chrome-will-an-error-in-code-invoked-from-the-dev-console-trigger-window-onerro

Comment: If you post that as an anwer I would be glad to accept it as the answer

Comment: You've also given me a good way to test my code (jfiddle) thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Will an error in code invoked from the dev console trigger window.onerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534054/chrome-will-an-error-in-code-invoked-from-the-dev-console-trigger-window-onerro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chrome Developer Console won't call the user-defined error event listener *if* the error is thrown immediately (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534068/603003) by [Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s)).

Throwing the error "just in time":

```
> window.onerror = function () {console.log('error!');};
function () {console.log('error!');}
> throw new Error();
Error
```

Throwing the error deferred:

```
> window.setTimeout(function() {throw new Error()}, 0);
xxxx
error!
Uncaught Error
```

(*xxxx* is the specific return value of `setTimeout()`)

---

Here is the original code snippet which led me to the point that the Chrome Dev Console changes the internal behaviour somehow:

```
// #btn is a simple button
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = "window.onerror=function(){alert('An error occurred!');};throw new Error('42');";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

This code is to be executed in a normal HTML file.

Comment: seems the same thing goes for Firefox