# JS: why window.onerror doesn't catch an error meta data

Tags: javascript

I open the chrome console and add function to catch all error in application:

```
window.onerror = function (a,b,c,d,e) {
  console.log('my handler: ', a,b,c,d,e);
}
```

I throw an exception in the same window but I got unreadable error data

```
setTimeout(() => { throw 'bla bla'; })
```

> my handler:  Script error.  0 0 null

[image]

Why I cannot read error message?

Comment: Possibly just related to the console.  Doing it in the console, it doesn't look like it is caught (in Firefox).  Though if I make a jsfiddle of it, it does get caught.

Comment: Also if you want to throw an actual Error, you need to `throw new Error('bla bla');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Will an error in code invoked from the dev console trigger window.onerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534054/chrome-will-an-error-in-code-invoked-from-the-dev-console-trigger-window-onerro)